# Why do I get an error of logits and labels broadcast?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I am trying to apply a CNN for classification. Model is as:

```
model=Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32,(3,3),input_shape=(150,150,3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Conv2D(32,(3,3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Conv2D(64,(3,3),padding='same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(64,(3,3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(512))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(num_classes))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
```

My error is as:

```
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-1116bc7b969c> in <module>
      5                             validation_steps=validation_num//batch_size,
      6                             callbacks=callbacks_list,
----> 7                             verbose=1
      8                             )
```

...
...

```
InvalidArgumentError:  logits and labels must be broadcastable: logits_size=[0,10] labels_size=[64,10]
     [[node categorical_crossentropy/softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits (defined at <ipython-input-12-1116bc7b969c>:7) ]] [Op:__inference_train_function_1083]

Function call stack:
train_function
```

My batch size is 64 and number of classes is 10. Can anyone please help me resolve this issue?

Comment: how are you calculating your loss? Can you post the code?

Comment: LR=1e-3
height=15
width=150
channels=3
seed=1337
batch_size=64
num_classes=10
epochs=200
data_augmentation=True
num_predictions=20
train_datagen=ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1./255,
    rotation_range=40,
    width_shift_range=0.2,
    height_shift_range=0.2,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    fill_mode='nearest'
)
...
...

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
loss='categorical_crossentropy',
metrics=['acc'])

Comment: This is a snippet of my code.

Comment: I have a snippet as: Found 1098 images belonging to 10 classes.
Found 272 images belonging to 10 classes.

Comment: and what does your model.fit(*) function look like?

Comment: it is as:
history=model.fit_generator(train_generator,
                            steps_per_epoch=train_num//batch_size,
                            epochs=epochs,
                            validation_data=train_generator,
                            validation_steps=validation_num//batch_size,
                            callbacks=callbacks_list,
                            verbose=1
                            )

This is where error displays.

Comment: Are your labels one hot encoded?

Comment: No. They aren't.